# Rails + SQL: Eager load 2 models with a SQL query involving 3 tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

**Outline**

Display info from a user's shows/episodes in descending ordered by last date modified of the show.

**Models/Relationships**

```
User
    has_many :shows

Show
    has_many :episodes
    belongs_to :user

Episode
    belongs_to :show
```

**My attempt**

@shows = Show.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Shows join Episodes on Episodes.id = Shows.episode_id and Episodes.user_id = '#{current_user.id}' ORDER BY shows.updated_at DESC")

**Problem**

My SQL query loads the User's shows in the appropriate order, however it does not eager load the appropriate episode -- leading to a N+1 problem.

How can I construct a query to eager load all of the information I need for show and episode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Don't use `find_by_sql`. If you're using it, you'll have to deal with such problems and ActiveRecord can't help you.

Try this one:

```
@shows = current_user.shows.preload(:episodes)
```

This will cause 2 queries, one for the `current_user`'s shows, and another one for all the episodes. Another option would be:

```
@shows = current_user.shows.joins(:episodes)
```

This will load everything with a single query. I personally prefer `preload` because it is more semantic and sometimes, with more complex queries, `joins` will likely break your query.

BTW: If you'd like to preload another relation, this could easily be done with sth. like this:

```
@shows = current_user.shows.preload(:host, :episodes => :author)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer. I ended up using: @shows = Show.eager_load(:episode).where("shows.id IN (select shows.id from shows join episodes on episodes.id = shows.episode_id and episode.user_id = ? ORDER BY shows.updated_at DESC)", current_user.id) . I am open to suggestions my query.